# Segmentation fault caused by copying QList

Tags: c++, qt, memory, segmentation-fault, qlist

lastly, I run into a very crazy Segfault. I have nothing done to my source code, the only thing I might have done is updated my QT Creator and MinGW. Now my program causes a segmentation fault, before that it works perfectly.

```
void Parameter::calculateKeyframes() {
    auto kfs = Bezier::calculateControlPoints(keyframes.values());
    for (auto kf : kfs) {
        setKeyframe(kf);
    }
    paramUpdate();
}
```

When it runs this function with a valid "keyframes" map, I know it thanks to debugging, it crashes in the Bezier::calculateControlPoints(QList) function at the marked line below.

```
QList<Keyframe> calculateControlPoints(QList<Keyframe> keyframes) {
    if (keyframes.size() < 2) {
        return keyframes;
    }

    int n = keyframes.size();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        Keyframe last_kf(0, ValueDouble(0.0));
        Keyframe kf;
        kf = keyframes.at(i);
        Keyframe next_kf(0, ValueDouble(0.0));

        if (-1 < i-1) last_kf = keyframes[i-1];
        else last_kf.frame = -1;

        if (keyframes.size() > i+1) next_kf = keyframes[i+1];
        else next_kf.frame = -1;

        if (kf.mode == Keyframe::STEP || kf.mode == Keyframe::LINEAR) continue;

        if (next_kf.frame > -1 && (kf.mode == Keyframe::EASEIN || (kf.mode == Keyframe::EASE && last_kf.frame < 0))) {
            double vecx_TtN = (double)next_kf.frame - (double)kf.frame; // vx = nx - x
            double vecy_TtN = next_kf.data.toDouble() - kf.data.toDouble(); // vy = ny - y

            kf.control2x = (double)kf.frame + vecx_TtN / 4.5; // x = x + vx / 4.5
            kf.control2y = (vecy_TtN / vecx_TtN) * (kf.control2x - kf.frame) + kf.data.toDouble(); // y = m * x + t
        } else if (last_kf.frame > -1 && (kf.mode == Keyframe::EASEOUT || (kf.mode == Keyframe::EASE && next_kf.frame < 0))) {
            double vecx_TtL = (double)last_kf.frame - (double)kf.frame; // vx = lx - x
            double vecy_TtL = last_kf.data.toDouble() - kf.data.toDouble(); // vy = ly - y

            kf.control1x = (double)kf.frame + vecx_TtL / 4.5; // x = x + vx / 4.5
            kf.control1y = (vecy_TtL / vecx_TtL) * (kf.control1x - kf.frame) + kf.data.toDouble(); // y = m * x + t
        } else if (kf.mode == Keyframe::EASE && last_kf.frame > -1 && next_kf.frame > -1) {
            double vecx_TtL = (double)last_kf.frame - (double)kf.frame; // vx = lx - x
            double vecx_TtN = (double)next_kf.frame - (double)kf.frame; // vx = nx - x

            double vecx_LtN = (double)next_kf.frame - (double)last_kf.frame; // vx = nx - lx
/* ---> */  double vecy_LtN = next_kf.data.toDouble() - last_kf.data.toDouble(); // vy = ny - ly

            kf.control1x = (double)kf.frame + vecx_TtL / 4.5; // x = x + vx / 4.5
            kf.control2x = (double)kf.frame + vecx_TtN / 4.5; // x = x + vx / 4.5
            kf.control1y = (vecy_LtN/vecx_LtN) * (kf.control1x - kf.frame) + kf.data.toDouble(); // y = m * x + t
            kf.control2y = (vecy_LtN/vecx_LtN) * (kf.control2x - kf.frame) + kf.data.toDouble(); // y = m * x + t
        }

        keyframes[i] = kf;
    }

    return keyframes;
}
```

It is caused in the second loop run because the "QList keyframes" has in its member with the index 0 (that means in the second run this member is also copied into "last_kf") an invalid pointer-address in the Keyframes "data" pointer. Now my question is why is data now a invalid pointer... in Parameter::calculateKeyframes() it wasn't.

Here my Keyframe.cpp (if it is important):

```
#include "keyframe.h"

#include "value.h"
#include "valuedouble.h"
#include <iostream>

Keyframe::Keyframe(long frame, Value v) : frame(frame), control1x(frame), control2x(frame), data(v), control1y(v), control2y(v) {
}

Keyframe::Keyframe() : Keyframe(0.0, ValueDouble(0.0)) {}

void Keyframe::toPipeKF(tutorial::Keyframe* k) {
    k->set_mode((tutorial::Keyframe_Mode)(int)mode);
    k->set_frame(frame);
    k->set_data((const char*)data.toByteArray());
    k->set_control1x(control1x);
    k->set_control1y(control1y.toByteArray());
    k->set_control2x(control2x);
    k->set_control2y(control2y.toByteArray());
}
```

Keyframe.h:

```
#ifndef KEYFRAME_H
#define KEYFRAME_H

#include "pipeendpoint.h"

#include "value.h"

class Keyframe {
public:
    Keyframe(long frame, Value v);
    Keyframe();

    enum Mode {
        STEP,
        LINEAR,
        EASEIN,
        EASE,
        EASEOUT,
        EASEFIX,
        EASECUSTOM
    };
    Mode mode = EASE;
    Value data;
    long frame;
    double control1x = 0;
    Value control1y;
    double control2x = 0;
    Value control2y;

    void toPipeKF(tutorial::Keyframe* kf);
};

#endif // KEYFRAME_H
```

Comment: Did you try to clean your project, rerun qmake and recompile after the update?

Comment: yeah... I have done that, but it doesn't help at all

Comment: What is `Value`? It looks like it's a class that gets sliced.

Comment: This is a class that handles a pointer to an abstract Class which represents multiple custom DataTypes...

Value:
https://pastebin.com/SLpn24xs
https://pastebin.com/629mbcW3

ValueBase:
https://pastebin.com/dTTR41Ee

ValueDouble (first and in the moment only one value):
https://pastebin.com/nud16nx9
https://pastebin.com/H2Md2w2r

Comment: @Panakotta00 *Here my Keyframe.cpp (if it is important):* -- It is `Keyframe` that may be the deciding factor here.  Please post this class.  In addition, why are you implementing a copy constructor and assignment operator for a class that seemingly has members that are not pointer?  What is wrong with the default version of these functions?

Comment: *I have nothing done to my source code, the only thing I might have done is updated my QT Creator and MinGW.* -- If you introduce undefined behavior to a program, then expect any behavior to occur at any time. Your issue has all the earmarks of this being the case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know exactly... as I said I have written this a little time ago. I have tested it now without... It doesn't have changed anything. And yeah I know... but how in the world can I know this, when it worked when I have written this.
https://pastebin.com/b8a5ZtxZ
https://pastebin.com/bmBVM63D

Comment: It is `KeyFrame.h` that you need to post here.

Comment: I have done that in my previous comment.

Comment: No, post the code *here*, not on an external link that may go away at any time.

Comment: Wow... the coding community evolved.., but okay...

Comment: OK, so the question is again, why did you feel the need to add a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator for `KeyFrame`?  I see nothing in that class that requires "extra help" in copying the `KeyFrame` object.  The default versions of those functions would be adequate (and will work correctly, 100% of the time).  The only issue is your `Value` class -- is that safely copyable and assignable?  If so, get rid of the `KeyFrame` copy constructor and assignment operator.  The more code you (unnecessarily) need to write, the more chance you introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: ok... copy constructor and assignment operator are removed, and now I have added an assignment Operator to my Value class... and it works... thank you!

Comment: ok, I don't know if the assignment operator is all you will need for `Value`.  You should also add a copy constructor for that class.